# Apagar PC utilizando el comando CMD en Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un textbox llamado `txtMinuto` y un botón llamado `btnApagar`. Quiero utilizar el comando `SHUTDOWN -s -t` que sirve para apagar la pc en un tiempo predeterminado pero cuando ejecuto mi linea de código para que se apague la PC según el tiempo que ingresé en mi textbox.

No se ejecuta correctamente mi linea de código:

```
private void btnApagar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int tiempo;
            int _result=0;
            String _minuto = txtMinuto.Text;
            tiempo = Convert.ToInt32(txtMinuto.Text);
            if (_minuto != "")
            {
                _result = (tiempo * 60);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe","SHUTDOWN -s -t "+ _result);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Comento por si le es útil. Yo también tengo un programa así y no ejecuta el comando shutdown si no se ejecuta como administrador (RunAs). Con otros usuarios no funciona

Comment: Si te lanza algun error, compartelo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: El problema son los argumentos que le pasas al comando no son -s -t es /s /t Si quieres puedes poner /f para forzar el apagado en caso de que una aplicación este abierta y te lo impida, siempre y cuando el ultimo argumento sea el tiempo /t

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos los que me ayudaron, ya logré arreglar mi código.

Comment: Podrias por favor compartir la respuesta como respuesta? esta bien visto responder tu propia pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ésto me funciona bien

```
Process.Start("shutdown","/s /t 0");
```

Sólo sería cuestión de agregar el textbox al parámetro del tiempo, algo así,

```
Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t '"+ int.Parse(textBox1.Text) +"'");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funcionó pero de esta manera Process.Start("shutdown", "-s -t " + _result);